# Extracting ReactDOM.render() calls to separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, code-standards

**Background**

My React app currently consists of 3 top-level components; a header, an explanation paragraph, and the app itself, wrapping a bunch of child components. The last part is fine, each child component is extracted into its own file and imported.

Now, in my main JavaScript file, I have those three components, and then at the bottom, I have a `ReactDOM.render(...)` call for each of them, which seems a bit untidy, especially if more components should be added later.

**Question**

According to today's standards, should these be extracted into their own files, and if so, what's the best (or at least *a good*) way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can create one main component and wrap other three components, and your code will look like this

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Header />
      <Paragraph />
      <Explanation />
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('put here your root id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use only one entry point for ReactDom.render

```
class App extends React.component {

render(){
       <div>
          <Header />
          <ParagraphExplanation />
      </div>

}

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('id'));
```

Comment: Ah ok, so just slap everything inside one big wrapper?

Comment: yes absolutely . Your APP component is the wrapper here